# Angular js how to replace text after last "/" in url (in textarea)

Tags: jquery, angularjs, performance

I need help to replace " 123" in this url "http://example.com/xyz/123" "123" value will vary.

1) I have model with drop down with URLs as options, selected URL will be displayed in a textarea. 
2) Text area has some text and URL that we select from dropdown. 
3) My issue is: I gave some text and selected URL from dropdown. then I select another URL from drop down this should replace first URL without changing text.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: kindly provide html and you code snippet, in jsfiddle for example

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is an angular or generic JavaScript Question. Since you did not provide code to manipulate on I will try to answer in generic fashion :)

place a watcher on your model which has dropdown selection, on the parent scope of the dropdown - if you are not creating any directive and just using ng-options to populate your dropdown that would your controller's scope.

```
$scope.url      - selected url 

$scope.$watch('url', function(newVal, oldVal){

     // make search-replace your preferred way ( regex, indexOf-splice )
     // on your textarea model.

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not really an angular problem, can be done with simple sure javascript:

```
// at some point of your code your var got this value
$scope.url = "http://example.com/xyz/123";

//and at another point you want to replace the value after the last '/'
var foo = $scope.url.split('/');
foo.pop(); // remove the last item
foo.push('new'); // add a different one
$scope.url = foo.join('/'); //join the string
```

// $scope.url is now "http://example.com/xyz/new"